# Can I use a subset of results from DESeq2 to calculate Bray-Curtis dissimilarity and then plot a PCoA?

Tags: r

I am having trouble using my results from DESeq2 when comparing the differential expression of bacterial genes between disease and control to then calculate the Bray-Curtis dissimilarity and subsequently plot a PCoA.

My output from DESeq2 I have saved as a data frame. It consists of 6000 rows which are the gene names, and two columns, one for p value ( all are <0.05) and one for log2FOldChange > 1. The data frame is called siggenes1. Do I need to normalize my data before running the Bray-Curtis and PCoA? I thought that this was already done through DESEq2, but looking at my code which I can provide, I haven't included normalisation=T when carrying out the DESeq2.

Or would I need to normalise using the sweep function the initial data prior to using DESeq2?

My code for Bray-Curtis Dissimilarity

```
 vegDistOut=vegdist(t(siggenes1),"bray")
```

The above gets 1 value which is 0.995. Now I am a bit lost as to how I would devise code for plotting a PCoA with this, as my next bit of code is wrong.

```
pcoaOut=pcoa(vegDistOut)
```

Error in array(STATS, dims[perm]) : 'dims' cannot be of length 0

I cannot proceed anymore because of the above steps.

If anybody could please help, I would be really grateful. 
Thank-you

Comment: Hi @Adam9, i really don't quite get what you are trying to do. If you use vegdist, you are calculating the distance between samples. Ok if you are using gene expression, then you should be given as input, the normalized gene expression table?

Comment: Hi @StupidWolf, my gene expression table is a csv with over 100000 genes as rows and then 8 columns, 4 disease and 4 control. The data can be described as a zero inflated negative binomial distribution. I have seen the sweep function used to "normalise" tables in this sense, some code would be                   totalgenecount = colSums(gct)
gctnorm = sweep(gct, MARGIN=2, totalgenecount/10^9, FUN="/")                                  with analysis done after this using t-test between the groups (I am using DESeq2 instead for the differential gene expression)....

Comment: And was wondering whether I need to complete a normalisation step like this prior to running the DESeq2? I understand that prior to PCA or PCoA I need to ensure data normalisation, I was wondering whether that might be why my downstream analysis attempts are not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to StackOverflow.

Bray-Curtis similarity is usually used when you try to determine how similar the *species composition* of two samples is. A typical input would consist of species counts per sample from software like [kraken](https://ccb.jhu.edu/software/kraken/), [clark](http://clark.cs.ucr.edu/) for high throughput data, or - in the case of 16S - [Qiime2](https://qiime2.org/):
 or [dada2](https://benjjneb.github.io/dada2/index.html).

```
|     Genus     |  Sample 1   |  Sample 2  |
|---------------|-------------|------------|
|  Pseudomonas  |     200     |    100     |
| Streptococcus |      50     |     20     |
```

You can of course calculate this metric for gene expression data, but that is not something that's commonly done and I would need more info on the *why* you want to do that.

As far as I understand your description you are interested in visualizing distances between your samples' expression in a PCA plot. Using DESeq2, you could:

```r
library(DESeq2)

# Get a DESeqDataSet from somewhere
dds <- DESeqDataSetFrom...(...)

# You don't need to run `DESeq()` on the dds for a PCA, just transform your data 
# into a homoscedastic dataset with either VST or rlog
vsd <- varianceStabilizingTransformation(dds, blind=TRUE)
rld <- rlogTransformation(dds, blind=TRUE)

# 'xxx' here takes the place of your condition of interest from your 
# design data frame
plotPCA(vsd, intgroup=c('xxx'))
```

All right, let's say you want actually to have the genes in your PCA, not the samples. In that case you could take the transformed expression values from the VST or rlog object and run the PCA code yourself:

```r
library(DESeq2)
library(ggplot2)

# Get gene expression post VST
vst_expr <- assay(vsd)
# Or - if you want to select some genes
vst_expr <- assay(vsd)[c(...), ]

# Perform PCA
pca <- prcomp(vst_expr)

# Calculate explained % variation
pvar_expl <- round(((pca$sdev ^ 2) / sum(pca$sdev ^ 2)) * 100, 2)

ggplot(as.data.frame(pca$x), aes(x = PC1, y = PC2)) + 
  geom_point() +
  xlab(paste("PC1: ", pvar_expl[1], "%")) +
  ylab(paste("PC2: ", pvar_expl[2], "%"))
```

For a final point, it is generally not advisable to select only a number of genes before performing exploratory data analysis, especially in the way that you are thinking of. You have tested these genes already for differential expression in DESeq2, so you know they are different. It's much better to perform a blind visualization using PCA's or heatmaps. Follow [this](http://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/workflows/vignettes/rnaseqGene/inst/doc/rnaseqGene.html) to learn all you need about DESeq2 and also check out https://support.bioconductor.org/

Comment: Hi @adam9, is this what you need? You can just feed t(assay(rld)) into vegdist and go on from there

Comment: Thank-you very much for your help. I will need to run the code and have a look at the outputs in a bit. Please could you tell me whether it would be possible to use the vegdist on a subset of genes which are significantly expressed in the disease vs control ( my data frame from the DESeq2 output contains around 6000 genes out of the 250,000 which are more expressed in disease vs control),  and would the transformations still apply? Sorry if these are stupid questions. I  have been advised to just look at the most differentially expressed ones. I do appreciate your replies.

Comment: IMO it's a bit non-sensical to calculate a similarity metric such as Bray-Curtis after removing data that is constant. Look at it this this way: All SDE genes that come out of DESeq2 are already known to be different in control vs. treatment so what is your similarity metric going to tell you? Of course your samples will be different when looking at only _things that change_ between samples. Since SO discourages long comment chains I'm happy to discuss the setup of your experiment somewhere else and we report back here once we find a solution

Comment: @BastianSchiffthaler                                                                                        
 using DF = data.frame(id=colnames(gctab),type=rep(c("ctrl","disease"),each=3))
dds = DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(gctab,DF,~type)

vsd <- vst(dds, blind=TRUE)
vegDistOut=vegdist(t(assay(vsd)),"bray"), gets an error of results may be meaningless because data have negative entries in bray. I understand why it would be incorrect to just choose the genes which are statistically significant. However, those that have done this in the class are not met with error messages

Comment: It would be good if you could upload a reproducible workflow, or your data. The error you are getting is because BC similarity should be calculated using a strictly positive value, but VST can produce negatives. You can `assay(vsd) + min(assay(vsd))` since your data is now homoscedastic and (pseudo)-log2 transformed. This essentially just moves the zero offset. Just don't try to relate the value back to any "real-world" meaning. Since your data is zero inflated, also have a look at e.g.: https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/zinbwave.html for preprocessing instead of VST

Comment: @BastianSchiffthaler Thank you for your reply. I have asked the question on here with my code, and a snapshot of my data is also there too, ( in order to avoid long comment chains). I believe rlog would get the same problem?  I will try vegDistOut=vegdist(t(assay(vsd)  + min(assay(vsd)),"bray") and see what happens.